# OpenCV VideoCapture says video has 0 frames (C++ and Python)

Tags: python, c++, opencv

I'm using OpenCV 2.4.9 and trying to open a video. `isOpened()` successfully runs, but when I try to look at the number of frames the video has, it returns 0, and I can't access the frames of the video. This happens with every video I have. I can use the same videos on a different machine (the issue happens in my CentOS 7 VM, the videos are in a shared folder and the host OS can access them fine in OpenCV). Ffmpeg is installed and I can `ffplay` the videos and `ffmpeg -i` tells me the videos have a nonzero number of frames. My OpenCV was compiled with ffmpeg successfully:

```
"  Video I/O:\n"
"    DC1394 1.x:                  NO\n"
"    DC1394 2.x:                  YES (ver 2.2.2)\n"
"    FFMPEG:                      YES\n"
"      codec:                     YES (ver 56.26.100)\n"
"      format:                    YES (ver 56.25.101)\n"
"      util:                      YES (ver 54.20.100)\n"
"      swscale:                   YES (ver 3.1.101)\n"
"      gentoo-style:              YES\n"
"    GStreamer:                   \n"
"      base:                      YES (ver 0.10.36)\n"
"      app:                       YES (ver 0.10.36)\n"
"      video:                     YES (ver 0.10.36)\n"
"    OpenNI:                      NO\n"
"    OpenNI PrimeSensor Modules:  NO\n"
"    PvAPI:                       NO\n"
"    GigEVisionSDK:               NO\n"
"    UniCap:                      NO\n"
"    UniCap ucil:                 NO\n"
"    V4L/V4L2:                    Using libv4l (ver 0.9.5)\n"
"    XIMEA:                       NO\n"
"    Xine:                        NO\n"
"\n"
```

My code correctly compiles and I can read images with OpenCV.

The code is incredibly basic. For Python:

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('test.mp4')
print cap.isOpened()
print cap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FPS)
print cap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)
>> True
>> 0.0
>> 0
```

And for C++:

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cv::VideoCapture cap;
    cap.open("test.mp4");
    if(cap.isOpened())
    {
        cout >> cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS) >> endl;
        cout >> cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT) >> endl;
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Which prints 0 as well.

Comment: can you try to write a video with VideoWriter class (e.g. mjpg codec) and try to load that one afterwards?

Comment: I did so. I still get 0 fps even though the video is rendered correctly.

Comment: but your other videos aren't rendered correctly? you wrote "and I can't access the frames of the video"

Comment: I can write a video correctly, and `ffplay` it, but I can't read a video, either a "real" video or one I synthesized with OpenCV.

Comment: ah ok, I interpreted "rendered correctly" to mean that you can read (and display/render) the frames but the number-of-frames-property was 0. Can you post your code?

Comment: I edited with my code. The code is incredibly simple and works fine on other machines.

Comment: but does it read frames? `cv::Mat img; cap >> img; std::cout << "image read: " << img.empty()==false << std::endl;`

Comment: Um, yeah, this is embarrassing. It does read the frame and I can display it. Why might `cap.get()` be lying to me then?

Comment: does `cap.get()` work in centOS without VM (if you have a machine to test it)? From what I've read, the VideoCapture class might show different behaviour for different OS or devices, especially the properties get and set are or aren't present for each device. But I don't even know which underlying low-level function is called for video property .get maybe you'll have to debug openCV yourself to locate the problem.

Comment: Does cap.set and cap.get of parameter `CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES` work?

Comment: `CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES` returns `185759637.0` when I call it on the video immediately after loading it.

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: I believe this is fixed in OpenCV 3.2. @ShivamGaur

Comment: Oh, okay. I did come across the same issue (where CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT returned 0 frames ) when using the python wrapper for opencv 3.2. But was able to fix it by installing `ffmpeg-devel`

Comment: Then maybe it's a codec issue as well. Good to know. Post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Same problem as @Hal T. Didn't work even after installing ffmpeg. I can read frames but cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT returns 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks similar to the codec issues I had, and described [in this stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44426099/opencv-cannot-read-ffmpeg-videos/44426100#44426100). In short: I used `ffmpeg` to convert the video:

`ffmpeg -i input.avi -c:v libx264 -vf format=yuv420p output.mp4`