# OpenCV cannot read ffmpeg videos

Tags: opencv, video, ffmpeg

I was unable to read video frames in OpenCV (python and c++) after using ffmpeg.

Specifically, I had the following problems:

1) unable to open the video file using `VideoCapture`.

2) able to open the video file using `VideoCapture`, but reading zero frames and/or receiving frames of size 0x0 pixels.

I am pasting my solution below, hoping this will help others.

These problems were encountered on Mac OS X Sierra 10.12.5, ffmpeg 3.2.4, Python 2.7.13, g++ 4.2.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) OpenCV cannot read as many video formats as ffmpeg. Therefore, it is often possible to play videos in VLC, but not to open them in OpenCV's `VideoCapture`. Hence, conversion with a tool such as `ffmpeg` is often required (see next point). One format that worked for me is h.264.

2) OpenCV seemed to require YUV420, whereas `ffmpeg` used YUV444 by default. Therefore, the following command solved my problems:

`ffmpeg -i input.avi -c:v libx264 -vf format=yuv420p output.mp4`